# Computer running very slow after new RAM installed

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory, performance

Operating system: Windows 7 32-bit (i'm aware of the 4gb RAM restriction here)

Display Adaptor: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 460 vram 1gb

Processor: AMD Phenom(tm)IIX4 965

HDD: Hitachi HDS723020BLA642 ATA device

Motherboard: Biostar a870

DVD.CD-ROM Drive: TSST corp CDRWDVD TS-H493B ATA Device

RAM: Kingston 2GB 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1066 Desktop Memory Model KVR1066D3S8N7K2/4G x 4
(This was my original set up)

Crucial Ballistix Sport 4GB 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1333 (PC3 10600) Desktop Memory Model BLS2KIT4G3D1339DS1S00 x 4
(this was gonna be the new setup)

I wanted to upgrade my RAM from 8gb to 16gb. After trying to put in the new RAM, the Crucial, my computer started to go very slow. Slow, meaning, taking ten minutes to start up and programs taking forever to load when clicked. I tried then to put my old Kingston RAM back in and it still booted up slow. The old Kingston RAM has never acted like this before until the Crucial was put in. I'm at a loss here.

Comment: What else did you do while you were upgrading the memory? Did you disconnect anything? Did you clean anything? Particularly, did you do anything at all to the CPU or heat sink? And check that that heat sink fan is still spinning.

Comment: Nothing,  just took out the old RAM and put the new RAM in. My heat sink fan turns, so does my power supply, graphics card, and two other fans that came with the tower. Should also note that safety mode works the way it should.

Comment: some boards have issues, when you use all RAM slots. So make a BIOS update and also check if your new RAM was tested on this board.

Comment: @user1725798 - Your more then likely not using supported memory based on the fact the new memory is an entirely different then what you were using.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install chipset drivers from CD that came with motherboard or from Biostar support site. I had similar issue once and this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Well, can your motherboard even handle the frequency and amount of the new RAM that you attempted to put in?

And yes there is the restriction so adding all that RAM doesn't do anything at all for your computer, except for the faster frequency which it seemed to not do so well after all. Look up the specs of what your motherboard can handle, and that RAM could be using more power than the last set you had, if you added a power supply with more wattage then it would also help with cooling along with keeping all of your components supplied with the right amount of power to make sure they aren't all struggling.

Also, make sure that your hard drive isn't fragmented. And after replacing new RAM, make sure to reset your CMOS battery on the motherboard, you should see a flat battery thats held into place, just pop it out for about 10-15 seconds then put it back in, that will restart some of the saved settings in your BIOS but also hopefully give it a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with some of the points here:

1- check the motherboard manual to ensure the MB can handle the specs of this new RAM

2- check with your motherboard makers web site and upgrade the BIOS if the revisions indicate covering this. That may help the above.

3- you're also putting in way more RAM than the OS can handle. I've heard of that causing troubles. If you address the above and are still having troubles, try taking 2 of the sticks out. Or even 3. If the RAM is OK otherwise, put it aside until you upgrade your OS.

Your problem is most likely the first which may be addressed by the second.

Hardware changes can take several reboots to settle in as the OS adapts. Sometimes, booting with incorrect hardware can damage the the MB but thats not likely here. You may want to try resetting the BIOS after you put the old RAM back in also. It may have reset to the new RAM, etc.