# Extra memory slows my laptop to a crawl

Tags: windows-7, memory

I have an Acer Aspire "TimeLine" 4810TZ, model MS2271 running Windows 7 (64-bit) with 3GB of RAM, which is comprised of a 2GB and a 1GB SODIMM - Both DDR3 with a frequency of 1066.

I was told that my laptop can handle up to 8GB.

I purchased a 4GB PC3 1066 card and swapped it for the 1GB one.

The machine boots up and works - but incredibly slowly, like literally 20x slower than it should.

CPU-Z reports that I indeed have 6GB of RAM with a DRAM frequency of 399MHz (the same frequency it was running with the previous RAM configuration).

If I take the new stick out, and/or use the new stick by itself, the system operates at the expected speed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try taking the new RAM stick out -- does it go back to the expected speeds?  How about if you use _just_ the new RAM stick?

Comment: @techie007: the answer to the first question is yes. I will try the second thing and report back.

Comment: Similar: [Computer running very slow after new RAM installed](http://superuser.com/questions/510137/computer-running-very-slow-after-new-ram-installed?rq=1)

Comment: Yes it works fine with just the new memory. I'll look at the answers in the other SO question.

Comment: Couple things to try: Try (re)seating them in opposite slots to what they were before, occasionally the order of the sticks are seen can affect things.  Try updating your BIOS (before putting all the RAM back in).

Comment: Do the memory timings match?

Comment: @ernie: everything is exactly 1066 - or are you referring to some different number?

Comment: I was asking about the [timings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_timings), not the frequency.  Should be three or four integers, split by hyphens.  If your new RAM has slower timings, the system may be running at those timings.